# "A component required a bean of type", but which one?

Tags: java, spring, dependencies

As the title mentioned, I have a `A component required a bean of type [SomeBean]` error and I would like to know which component requires `[SomeBean]`. Is there a way to get more information on which bean requires the missing one?

Also, why do I get this error message? I am pretty sure that sometime missing beans generate a clearer message stating what beans require the missing ones.

Why I am asking:

I am trying to make a spring application that is similar to another (working) one, and use many similar beans. But I have trouble following the bean dependencies. So I removed one bean of the working application and run it in order to know where and how this component is used.

=> So, in general, I am looking for good ways to track bean dependencies in complex contexts.

Some time my IDE (intellij ultimate 2019) gives me some information, but here it doesn't. Maybe because the dependencies span a few packages, many being outside the application code, and use AutoConfiguration. Don't know...

If I use the spring diagram, it generates something that is not really readable (too meany beans). And the diagram is more a list of found beans structured by where there are provided, not the bean dependency diagram: my application list the beans it provides, and the autoConfig list the beans it provides. But It doesn't tell what bean of the autoConf is using which bean that my app provides. Or maybe I just don't understand how it works.

Comment: Note: I think maybe spring didn't tell me which bean requires the missing one because the failing code is actually making a direct lookup in the spring context (`context.getBean`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default log configuration echoes messages to the console as they are written. By default, `ERROR`-level, `WARN`-level, and `INFO`-level messages are logged. You can also enable a “debug” mode by starting your application with a `--debug` flag.

So, indeed, you should enable that debug mode to see a more detailed log information about your error, which seems to be a missing required bean dependency.

See some more detailed info about in [Spring Loggin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

Comment: Tx. I simply added `debug: true` in my `application.yml`. I prints lots of stuff, abut loaded beans, and the stack trace of the error.